# New Graph not getting displayed on Canvas PySimpleGUI and Matplotlib

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I need to reset the graph based on two buttons. It displays the first graph if button1 pressed but no the second one after pressing button2.

First graph is shown properly but need to clear the canvas

Code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as psg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

def make_graph_and_put_on_canvas(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, graph_title, canvas):

    figure,ax=plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set(xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel,
           title=graph_title)
    ax.grid()

    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

    return figure_canvas_agg

if __name__ == '__main__':
   layout = [[psg.B("Button1"),psg.B("Button2")],[psg.Canvas(key="canvas")]]
   Graph = psg.Window(title="Graph", layout=layout, size=(500, 500))
   while (True):
        event, Value = Graph.read()
        if event == psg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            Graph.close()
            break
        if event=="Button1":
            #Make the first graph for y=2x
            x=[0,1,2,3]
            y=[0,2,4,6]
            make_graph_and_put_on_canvas(x, y, "x", "y", "title",Graph["canvas"].TKCanvas)

        if event=="Button2":
            # Make the first graph for y=3x
            x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
            y = [0, 3, 6, 9]
            make_graph_and_put_on_canvas(x, y, "x", "y", "title",Graph["canvas"].TKCanvas)
```

Answer (score 0):

`FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)` will create a new canvas in `Graph["canvas"].TKCanvas`.
With option `side='top'` when `pack`, you will get the new canvas from top to bottom of `Graph["canvas"].TKCanvas`. Second `Button` did make second graph but on bottom of your window, invisible for `size = (500, 500)` in your window.

- call following code once if you want new graph show on same figure,

```py
figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
```

- clear figure or axis by

```py
clf()    # clear figure
cla()    # clear axis
```

- update figure on canvas after all plots on figure done

```py
figure_canvas_agg.draw()
```

Following code just work, not optimized.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as psg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

def make_graph_and_put_on_canvas(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, graph_title, canvas):

    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set(xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel, title=graph_title)
    ax.grid()
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()

    return figure_canvas_agg

if __name__ == '__main__':

    layout = [[psg.B("Button1"),psg.B("Button2")],[psg.Canvas(key="canvas")]]
    Graph = psg.Window(title="Graph", layout=layout, size=(500, 500), finalize=True)
    figure, ax = plt.subplots()
    canvas = Graph["canvas"].Widget
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

    while (True):

        event, Value = Graph.read()

        if event == psg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break

        if event=="Button1":
            # Make the first graph for y=2x
            x=[0,1,2,3]
            y=[0,2,4,6]
            make_graph_and_put_on_canvas(x, y, "x", "y", "title1", canvas)

        if event=="Button2":
            # Make the first graph for y=3x
            x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
            y = [0, 3, 6, 9]
            make_graph_and_put_on_canvas(x, y, "x", "y", "title2", canvas)

    Graph.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, I did not understand how to use it. I will be really grateful if you can make the changes to the code shared above. I want to plot one graph on the canvas at a time. But the graph should change depending on the button.

Comment: Update as above.

Comment: Works now. Thanks alot. Along with your edits, one important step that I missed in my code was to add `finalize=True` in `sg.Window` command.  I am not sure why it is necessary since I have `window.read()`.

Anyways Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Before window finalized or `window.read()`, tkinter not initialized and canvas still not exist, so you cannot link matplotlib with canvas.